# No resource ident ifier found for attribute 'widgetCategory' in package 'android'

Tags: android, compilation

widgetCategory was added in Android 4.2 SDK level 17. I decompiled an APK with apktool, added the widgetCategory attribute to a xml file, and recompiled.

The error is this:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'widgetCategory' in package 'android'
```

I have tried using the latest aapt and changing the sdk level in apktool.yml but neither solved the problem.

Is there anything I need to change to add support for Android 4.2 to apktool?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set build target to API 17. In Eclipse you can achieve this by right clicking on the project and choose Properties. Then, under Android, select Android 4.2 as build target. It's also possible to just open the file project.properties and set target to `android-17`.

You do **not** have to change either `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` in the Android Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself. You need to update the MinSdkVersion of the App (in the manifest.xml) to 17.

If it uses a MinSdkVersion below 17, it will not recognize the widgetCategory resource.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello. I added <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/> to the manifest file but the same error still occurs. Are you using a special version of apktool or appt? thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are geared towards someone using Eclipse and Java when the OP said he's using apktool. Most likely the problem is apktool is using a framework SDK file below level 17. https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/FrameworkFiles