# intelliJ android: No resource identifier found for attribute 'widgetCategory' in package 'android'

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk, android-appwidget

I opened an intelliJ project that i successfully built in the past and havent made any changes to. Only a couple of months ago it was fine.

I cant build it now because i get the error:
"No resource identifier found for attribute 'widgetCategory' in package 'android'"
*android:widgetCategory="" is inside the tag 
*no support library is required for this function

I went through all the suggestions at the question by this exact name that can be found at: [No resource ident ifier found for attribute 'widgetCategory' in package 'android'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390852/no-resource-ident-ifier-found-for-attribute-widgetcategory-in-package-android)
Those suggestions didnt fix my problem (They relate to a different IDE but make a lot of sense)

The whole project build target is API 18. yet i get this error. Appwidget provider functions are introduced from API 3 and API 16.

I stripped all the IntelliJ baggage from the project and reimported it from scratch. same error.

I know the app runs fine on any android device API8 and up, but I cant compile it to create another apk, and i want to be able to change the app. I feel its an IntelliJ/SDK issue, but I dont know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make a small edit to AndroidManifest and save it. eg, add then delete a space.

I borrowed this trick from Eclipse to use in IntelliJ, after posting the question. It seems quite inconceivable that this would work. After I did this, building on API 18 was able to compile code from API16 - but not before. Weird.

I did notice something else about IntelliJ. In the past i was able to compile code that had elements from a higher API than the build target. I get that in the last few months this has changed (mid 2014). Now the build target must be set to include every little bit of code in the project. By that i DONT mean the targetSDKversion in the manifest, set that to whatever you want.